# jquery validate() issue

Tags: jquery, validation

i use the validate plugin a lot  - its great.
my current setup, is a fix "closed" boxes, which contain fields.
what i want to do, is if the box contains mandatory fields which were not filled, the boxes should open trying to submit.

this is my code:

```
$("#ftblSubGroupsadd").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        alert('Note, a few mandatory fields remain un-answered. You may have to open some closed boxes');
        $("label.error").closest("div[class=inside]").css("display","block");
        $("label.error").closest("div.boxed").removeClass().addClass('box');
    }
  });
```

and [here](http://tapnack.net/opentest.html) is an online demo.

the weird thing is that when you try submkit the first time, all you get is the alert().
but is you straight away click submit again, you get the alert() and only then, does the open/show code function, and the boxes open.

can someone give me a hand with why this is the case?

thanks!

Comment: don't use `.removeClass()` that will remove `error` class too which is must to stop in case of error. instead use `.removeClass(validClass).addClass(errorClass);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, someone helped me on another list, and this code seems to work:

```
$("#ftblSubGroupsadd").validate({
    showErrors: function(){
        this.defaultShowErrors();
        //alert('Note, a few mandatory fields remain un-answered. You may have to open some closed boxes');
        $("label.error").closest("div[class=inside]").css("display","block");
        $("label.error").closest("div.boxed").removeClass().addClass('box');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem is that the class label.error is added after your code is executed: that is the reason why the first time it doesn't run correctly and why it runs ok the second time.

EDIT - i found out a solution (i think):

```
$("#ftblSubGroupsadd").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        alert('Note, a few mandatory fields remain un-answered. You may have to open some closed boxes');
        $.each(validator.currentElements, function(i, el){
            if(! validator.element(el)){
                $(el).closest("div[class=inside]").css("display", "block");
                $(el).closest("div.boxed").removeClass().addClass('box');
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/3Vw4y/4/

Comment: mmm... interesting Nicola.
is there some kind of live() method i can use to overcome this?

Comment: If you post your code on jsfiddle.net tomorrow morning i'll look at some kind of solution, right now i'm on mobile!:)

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate it. Its my first time posting there, so hopefully it worked out ok.
URL is: http://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/3Vw4y/2/

Comment: I updated my answer and your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/3Vw4y/4/

Comment: ok - i just saw this now, after i posted another solution. yours seems to do the trick too. thanks muchly!!